# "igraph0" package installation

Tags: r, igraph

I want to use gspan algorithm for graph mining and use below command in R:

```
results <- gspan(database)
```

then i faced with this error:

```
Error in library(igraph0) : there is no package called ‘igraph0’
```

then I installed *Rtools* and I wanted to install 'igraph0' package in R on windows 10. I downloaded *"igraph0_0.5.5-1.tar"* from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph0/

Then I tried to import this package to R with this command:

```
install.packages("~/R/igraph0_0.5.5-1.tar.gz",type="source",repos=NULL, dependencies=TRUE)
```

but I faced with below error. Please help me:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'igraph0'
* removing 'C:/Users/Maryam/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/igraph0'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Maryam\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" "C:/Users/Maryam/Documents/R/igraph0_0.5.5-1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Maryam/Documents/R/igraph0_0.5.5-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Any good reason not to use `igraph` ?

Comment: `igraph0` is deprecated and removed from CRAN. You should just use `igraph`

Comment: Do you have Rtools on your system?